# Plot image function together maintaining compatibility between their coordinate systems?

Tags: plotting, image

Is it possible to plot an image, i.e., draw it's pixels against usual coordinates?
My goal is to plot my image and my function in the same coordinates.

**Update**

I drew an image of size `200x100` and drew a spot at `100,50`. When plotting it should coincide with actual coordinates, but it doesn't.

[image]

i.e. image takes random size and random scale both unrelated with plot size and scale. While I need each pixel be located at it's correct coordinates, not only image corner.

**Update 2**

Why `Image` is not a `Graphics` primitive or directive?

Comment: Can you supply the code for your function, its plot, and your image? You haven't given us much to work with.

Comment: The image pixels are square so you will need to use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` in your plot.

Comment: If you would rather have the image distort to match the aspect ratio of the plot, you could use `Prolog -> Raster@Reverse@ImageData@im`

Comment: @SimonWoods your last suggestion was what I looked for

Comment: @SuzanCioc. Please write up the solution you have settled on as an answer.

Comment: You have to set up `AspectRatio` if you specify the `PlotRange`: `AspectRatio -> 1/Divide @@ ImageDimensions[im]`.

Comment: Regarding your "update 2," that's like asking for the difference between a .png file and a vector format such as .eps. `Image` is an object encapsulating a matrix representing the colors of the various pixels, whereas a `Graphics` object contains just the information for how to create an image.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want something like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Prolog -> Inset[ex, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {Automatic, 1}]]
```

First you plot your function and then, using `Inset`, you insert your image into the plot. The fourth parameter given to `Inset` is the size given in the coordinate system of the plot.

`Prolog` draws the image before the plot is drawn. `Epilog` would do the same but draw the image after the plot is drawn, on top of it.